# Sending emails in PHP

Tags: php

I am creating a website using bootstrap, HTML and PHP. Whenever I am sending emails via mail function, many recipients are unable to receive the email as my host told me that using a php mailer on a shared server like SH-2499957 is not a good idea. What other options do I have to send emails through PHP, that would not cause this problem?

Comment: i bet the gmail api would suit you well..

Comment: Get your host support  to configure smtp to send mails.  Otherwise.  You can configure  third party smtp's like Gmail or Yahoo for free of cost.  You can go with sendgrid or mailgun  as well.  It's depending upon your convince.

Comment: any update on what you decided to go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just signed up for [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) and it's a great resource for developers. 10,000 free emails per month, easy setup, great API, one less attack vector on your server, and your outgoing emails are way less likely to go to spam. I have an existing mail server that works great but I'm in the process of switching over because mails sent through the cloud tend to have a higher open rate.

> **Mailgun Example** for PHP:

```
$mailgun->sendMessage("mail.example.com",[
'from'    => 'Your Company <noreply@mailgun.net>',
'to'      => 'Excited User <example@mailgun.net>',
'subject' => 'Hello World',
'text'    => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try an external service like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/). I know that SendGrid provides a PHP library for easy integration as well as through SMTP and a web API. They also provide 12,000 free emails per month.

**SendGrid example**:

```
// using SendGrid's PHP Library - https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($api_user, $api_key);
$email    = new SendGrid\Email();

$email->addTo("test@sendgrid.com")
      ->setFrom("you@youremail.com")
      ->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun")
      ->setHtml("and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");

$sendgrid->send($email);
```

From https://sendgrid.com/

Other alternatives include [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/), [RailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/), [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/), and [MailJet](https://www.mailjet.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Mandrill API, you can track your mails(Sent, Bounced, Delivered etc.), statistics and all. Add Templates with Ease. Check the documentation [here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gmail (or any other SMTP-compatible email provider) with [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library. Consider that you can't use services like Gmail to broadcast a large number of emails.